# Join Tables by Condition in R

Tags: r, join, conditional-statements

I've two tables I would like to join by condition.

```
Data_1 <- data.frame(Section_A = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"), 
                     ID1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23), 
                     Key = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","A","B","B","A","B","C","C"))

Data_2 <- data.frame(Section_B = c("d","d","d","d","d","d","e","e","e","f","f","f","f","f","f"), 
                     ID2 = c(31,32,33,34,35,36,41,42,43,54,55,56,57,58,59), 
                     Key = c("B","B","A","A","C","A","C","B","A","C","A","A","C","B","A"))
```

The following conditions must be satisfied when joining the tables.

1. Section_A "level a" can "receive" no more than 2 (count(ID2) for Section_A(a) <= 2)
2. Section_A "level b" can "receive" no more than 1 (count(ID2) for Section_A(b) <= 1)
3. Section_A "level c" can "receive" no more than 2 (count(ID2) for Section_A(c) <= 2)
4. Section_B "level d" can "give" no more than 2 (count(ID2) for Section_B(d) <= 2)
5. Section_B "level e" can "give" no more than 2 (count(ID2) for Section_B(e) <= 2)
6. Section_B "level f" can "give" no more than 1 (count(ID2) for Section_B(f) <= 1)
7. Any of ID1 and ID2 can't repeat itself in the joined table.

The expected outcome is:

```
Expected_Outcome <- data.frame(Section_A = c("a","a","b","c","c"), 
                               ID1 = c(1,2,10,20,21), 
                               Key = c("A","A","C","B","C"),
                               Section_B = c("d","d", "e","e","f"),
                               ID2 = c(33,34,41,42,57))
```

Comment: Hi BMM. Can you show us what you already tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Hi @dario I tried left join: Expected_Outcome <- left_join(Data_1, Data_2, by="Key") but I struggled to address the constraints (conditions listed) (I'm fairly new to r).

Comment: @dario Did you get a chance to look at my question? Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I don't see an obvious answer to your problem. I also have a feeling that there are multiple possible resulting outcomes, depending on the order of the rows you try to bind. It would take me quite some time to come up with a good answer to this problem. You will have to do this yourself but feel free to ask here again if you have a concrete question. Sorry that I couldn't give you a "ready to use" solution. As a last tip here what I would try: Use a loop, take one row, check the conditions, append it accordingly, move on to next row...). Best of luck!

Comment: The order of the rows shouldn't change. I'm working on it as well but not successful so far. I couldn't understand what you meant by "concrete question".